# SVN how to ignore a directory

Tags: svn, directory, ignore

i'm currently typing, which works...

```
svn propset svn:ignore IgnoreMe C:\test\IgnoreMe
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to state it without specifying "IgnoreMe" before the directory.  As in to just state the path, like...

```
svn propset svn:ignore C:\test\IgnoreMe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not ignore absolute directories in SVN but ignore directory or more general pattern relative to the current directory.

In case you're in directory **C:\test** you need to issue a

```
svn propset svn:ignore IgnoreMe
```

to ignore directory **C:\test\IgnoreMe**

Comment: oh I see so there's no way to ignore it without being in the directory...Thanks!

Comment: Of course there is, just provide a path so it doesn't default to working directory.

Answer (score 1):

That's not now `svn:ignore` is supposed to work. You can't set that property in the ignored item—if you remove it from version control, you can't assign version control properties to it!

You have to set the property in the parent directory:

```
svn propset svn:ignore IgnoreMe C:\test\
```

Wildcards are allowed as well:

```
svn propset svn:ignore Ignore* C:\test\
svn propset svn:ignore * C:\test\
```