# How do I to deprecate a directory in svn?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to set the depth of a directory from `infinity` to `empty`?

```
$ ls .
Foo/     Bar/
```

`Foo/` and `Bar/` are both of depth `infinity` but `Foo/` is deprecated. I don't want to delete Foo because it could still be useful. However svn will still keep checking for updates in `Foo/`, which is time-consuming because it's a big folder. So I want to stop svn from checking for updates Foo because it's not going to change, even if it means removing it locally.

So if I do the following:

```
$ rm -fr Foo
$ svn up --depth empty Foo
```

it works. But when I do `svn up` it just re-downloads the whole directory... terrible. So I try this:

```
$ rm -fr Foo
$ svn up --set-depth empty Foo
```

and svn just gets seemingly stuck forever, so after 5-10 minutes I lose patience and kill the process.

Why does it get stuck? Am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternative way to get what I'm looking for?

I thought of doing something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187600/svn-how-to-ignore-a-directory), but wouldn't changing the properties effect other users accessing the repository? I want a solution that only affects my own local repository.

Comment: Why don't you simply delete the directory? SVN will keep it in its history.

Comment: Good point. I can't delete it because other users might still need it (even though it's deprecated), so it needs to stay there for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

delete it.  It will always be there, anyone that needs it can always get it from svn.

Comment: Actually I realised that the problem with `svn up --set-depth empty Foo` worked but it was deleting stuff locally. I was using an encrypted disk image as thus this would take forever. It took less time to just check out a fresh copy.